# MVC View trying to parse 2 strings in Details view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
<h1 @if(Model.unittype == "PRP" && Model.name =="TTO"){string x = "CISCO";}else x = "---";>x</h1>
```

not a chance.  if its just done in html locally thats fine, shouldnt have to go back to the server.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ternary operator along with an explicit code nugget (wrap the code in `()`)

```
<h1>@(Model.unittype == "PRP" && Model.name =="TTO" ? "CISCO" : "---")</h1>
```